# Usage of non-argument variables in rxjs operators

Tags: rxjs5

Let's say there is function that returns observable, and the function has an argument

```
getObservable(arg){
   return obs$.pipe(map(data => { // wanna use arg here }));
}
```

I am probably being paranoid here but it always confuses me if I can use `arg` inside map's callback and therefore I use `combineLatest` or `withLatestFrom` to send `arg` inside operator which feels redundant, but I am not sure.

```
getObservable(arg){
   return combineLatest(of(arg), obs$).pipe(
     map(([arg, data]) => {})
   );
}
```

Could there be any problem if I go with the first way?

Comment: Of course you can use `arg` because it comes from parent's scope.

Comment: I know that I have access to it, but I'm worried it's value may have changed while observable waiting for response.